# NodeJS - Couple and debounce events

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm currently struggling with a solution for the following problem: in my app you can subscribe to an event like "power off this light" or "dim this light to 0.5", this is fine but..

There might be a case where both "power off this light" and "dim this light to 0.5" are fired with little time in between, to prevent flickering and making sure the right decision in what command to send to make I need to have a method to debounce the events and if the specified 2 events occur in a given period just fire one event with the two events "bundled".

What would be the best approach to solve this? I've found some debouncing solutions here, but am not sure how to do this with two (or more) unrelated events.

This is how far I have come so far. Can someone push me in the right direction?

```
   public registerMultiListener(capabilities: Array<string>, callback: MultipleCapabilityCallback, timeout: number = 500): void {
        let s: NodeJS.Timeout;
        let valuesMap: Map<string, any> = new Map();
        let settingsMap: Map<string, object> = new Map();

        capabilities.forEach((capability: string) => {
            this.registerCapabilityListener(capability, (newValue: any, settings: object) => {
                valuesMap.set(capability, newValue);
                settingsMap.set(capability, settings);

                clearInterval(s);
                s = setInterval(() => {
                    callback(valuesMap, valuesMap);
                }, timeout)
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the debouncing concept try to reduce the time-consuming work. To achieve this delay can be added so it will wait for some time. So, if rebounding observes that no new input is provided then he can call to another work.

As per your requirement what you can do keep some delay on the input side and observe that any new input coming in this certain time eg.2seconds If new input comes then increase or add delay by 2 seconds or else you can reset to 2 seconds and again wait for 2 seconds. If you are not getting any new input till 2 seconds then fire your next work function. 
I hope, your doubt may clear